# Convert a datatable to IList c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i got a code for converting datatable to ilist. which may work but the code not very clear to me. here is code

```
table.AsEnumerable()
.Select(r => table.Columns.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c]))
.ToList();
```

**what is table.Columns.ToDictionary()...what it does. what is the meaning of c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c]
what r[c] return. not very clear to me.**

i got a another snippet....here it is

```
var list = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
   list.Add(row);

return list;
```

this code is clear to me but i want to know which code has good performance out of 2 different snippet. please discuss. thanks

Comment: That code is a memory killer and it's also useless because [`DataColumnCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.aspx) is already implemented as HashTable (when you query the column [by name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ToDictionary` call converts each `DataRow` to a `Dictionary<string, object>` which you can use to find the value of any field within the row. `=>` is the syntax used in a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - you should really learn about lambda expressions if you're going to do any significant amount of work with LINQ.

Your second snippet would be more simply written as:

```
var list = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

In terms of efficiency - the first form fetches all the data from the row as it builds the dictionary. That's likely to make it less efficient if you only need to look at some of the fields. On the other hand, it *may* be more convenient. It depends on what you do with it later. In terms of memory, the second form will mean the `DataRow` objects themselves can't be garbage collected, whereas the first form doesn't need the rows afterwards - but it's created a copy of all the actual data. Whether that's relevant in your situation will again depend on the rest of your code.

I wouldn't focus on the performance to start with though - start off with whichever code makes the rest of your application simplest to write, then check whether that performs *well enough*.

Comment: Both snippetes are pretty useless in my opinion. The first creates 1000 dictionaries for 1000 `DataRows` although [`DataRow.Item(String colname)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5) already uses a HashTable internally. The second creates a `List<DataRow>`, but the `DataTable` already stores all DataRows in-memory.

Comment: thanks for ur explanation. i need to know how this line c => r[c] give value. if r is datarow and c is column then how it is giving the value. put some light.

Comment: can u plzz elaborate c => r[c] this line in detail.

Comment: @Thomas: That's the element selector of [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx). It just specifies what should be the value of each [`KeyValuePair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) in the `Dictionary`. In this case the field of the `DataRow` (of type object).

Comment: Is that code supposed to be `var list = table.AsEnumerable().ToList();`, per System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, `var list = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();` without requiring that assembly, or some other voodoo I'm not familiar with?  DataRowCollection isn't IEnumerable<DataRow>, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @JoeAmenta: You're right - I've changed it to `Cast`, although it does suggest that the OP's original code wouldn't work either. Possibly this is a strongly-typed datatable? Does that have a different `Rows` property hiding the general one?

Answer (score 1):

Well to put it simply its a lambda expression that translates into a method. r is an object and c is its indexer. that means you can select one of r's array values. Example: from table R return me column number 8 so c will have the value of 8. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for ur explanation. i need to know how this line c => r[c] give value. if r is datarow and c is column then how it is giving the value. put some light.

Comment: well to put it simply, you have a table row object that contains 10 columns. by doing this row[2] you are telling him give me column number 2 of this row. The r will also be an int because a table has more rows and of course a row has many columns. That's as simple as i can put it.

Comment: To translate it into a method(because that's what it is) it looks about like this.    object Column(int rowNumber) { return columnNumber x from rowNumber x; }; just an vague explanation.

Answer (score 1):

They are different in their results.

Short:

- The first statement creates a list of dictionaries, where each key-value pair is column name and value. The `ToDictionary` extension method expects two parameters: a key and a value. The key is in this example the column name (`c => c.ColumnName`). Because this method is invoked on the `Columns`-collection of your datarow, `c` is a column. The second parameter takes the column name and inserts it into the current row, giving the actual value for the column. So your dictionary gets filled with KeyValuePairs consisting of ColumnName->Value. This is done for each row. Afterwards the ToList() function returns a list of dictionaries.
- The second example just fills a list with the DataRows, the result has no advantage over using the `Rows` collection of the datatable.

Comment: thanks for ur explanation. i need to know how this line c => r[c] give value. if r is datarow and c is column then how it is giving the value. put some light.

Comment: @Thomas: `r` is the datarow and has an index operator defined which allows access by `r[index]` where index can be an integer (the i-th column) or the column object itself. `r["id"]` for example would yield the "id" column of the datarow `r`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use .Net Framework 3.5 then try this
code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var list = dt.Select().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `table.AsEnumerable()` does very similar thing as entire SECOND code snippet
and you can use either of them.

The code:

```
.Select(r => table.Columns.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c]))
.ToList();
```

creates dictionary with values for the each table row. You probably do not need this at all because the DataRow already has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of code performance, I agree with previous posters that, at first you should not concern yourself with speed.  Get it working, then get it right.

However, based on the (limited) research I've seen on benchmarks between a standard foreach loop and the LINQ fluent syntax, LINQ is only slightly slower than a standard foreach loop...and when dealing with small sets of data, it's an insignificant amount of slowness.  I'm currently conducting some independent statistical analysis on this subject as time allows.